# Accessing struct data in better way

Tags: c++, c++11

I have files with values like below:

```
[A]
Ranges=5
LowRanges=000000000
HighRanges=299999999
Service=01
```

There are 36 blocks of these. Going from A to Z then 0 to 9.
I need to read the file and save data to be accessed later. 
so i created vector of structures.

```
struct values
{
    uint32_t LowRangesValue;
    uint32_t HighRangesValue;
    int Service;
    string key;
};
vector<values> data;
```

In main func:

```
ifstream f("file.txt");
if (f.is_open()){
    values pt;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 35; i++){
        pt.key = char(65 + i);
        pt.HighRangesValue_[0] = 123456789 + i;
        pt.LowRangesValue_[0] = 222555888 + i;
        pt.Service = 968 + i;
        data.push_back(pt);

    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 35; i++){ //is this efficient?
        if (data[i].key == "C"){
            int s = PTNdata[i].Service;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, every time i need some info from this, i need to use last loop for 36 times. is the way i am accessing data from my vector, most efficient way or any other way is there to do it better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use associative array `std::unordered_map` or `std::map`. Also you can use `std::vector` index as key for your specific case.

Comment: use key in a `std::map`, alternatively as your list is sorted and always contains all the elements you can calculate the value of `i` rather than checking every one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is what you need for this.

```
std::unordered_map<char, values> values_map;

values pt;
// ... populate pt

values_map.insert({'A', pt});
```

later you could access each element in a constant time:

```
values pt_c = values_map['c'];
```

You could also use [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), if you need the keys to be sorted and iterate elements in order. It would be less efficient, but still faster then searching in `vector`.

Comment: `std::vector` can be faster in this case

Comment: I wonder if in such simple case, `std::map` would indeed be slower.

Comment: actually yes, iterating `vector` could be fasted then `map` in case of 35 elements

Comment: @Heavy you do not need to iterate, as vector is already sorted or can be easily sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straighforward solution is to calculate index based on key, as there is limited range:

```
size_t keyToIdx( char k )
{
    if( k >= 'A' and k <= 'Z' ) return k - 'A';
    if( k >= '0' and k <= '9' ) return 26 + k - '0';
    throw std::runtime_error( "invalid key" );
}
```

then just use it to access elements in the vector:

```
int s = PTNdata[keyToIdx('C')].Service;
```

without loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you always have 36 values, 'A' - 'Z', '0' - '9', then why do you need to loop to access? In your vector surely it is stored sequentially (or can be sorted to fit this way). You can likely do an immediate lookup by simply having a function like this:

```
constexpr size_t positionInVector(char val) {
    if (val >= '0' && val <= '9') return 26 + val - '0';
    if (val >= 'A' && val <= 'Z') return val - 'A';
    return std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(); // obvious error code.
}
```

To get the index into the vector based on the char value that you used to enter it.